# Import calendar events in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, events

I want to import events in my wordpress from an external source.

The events are one-time events and instead of creating them one by one by hand I would like to import them.

The events are who has duty to staff the bar at the sportclub at a given day, and it has to be imported twice a year, when a new schedule is created.

**We don't have to deal with updates and deletes** because if we make changes to the schedule we edit the wordpress events by hand, so no complex syncing etc.

The nicest solution would be to import from a file, but I can also publish it to a url.

**The schedule is in our custom MS-Excel format, so I can create any file/record format I want from it**, so that won't be the problem.

As far as I know we do not use a custom event plugin so it's regular Wordpress events.

**EDIT**

I thought events was simply basic behaviour of wordpress, but apparently it is not.

We are using Timely’s All-in-One Event Calendar

Comment: WordPress doesn't have "regular" events. I'd recommend a plugin that allows import from a CSV you can customize. The Event Calendar Pro/Event Espresso both have import options although The Events Calendar Pro is cheaper.

Comment: I thought events was simply basic behaviour of wordpress, but apparently it is not.

We are using Timely’s All-in-One Event Calendar

Comment: BULK CSV UPLOAD
Import events into your calendar by uploading files containing event feeds in either comma-separated values (CSV) or iCalendar (.ics) format. <-- did you see that?

Comment: Yes, now I do ;-) The key to the solution was you mentioning that WordPress doesn't have "regular" events. I was looking for out of the box solutions because I assumed (yeah, foolish of me ;-)) that WordPress had a event system built in. So now I've read the docs from the Timely’s All-in-One Event Calendar , I see the support for .ics and CSV format

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WP Event Aggregator](https://xylusthemes.com/plugins/wp-event-aggregator/) which can import your events from Facebook, MeetUp, Eventbrite, and other iCal-supported calendars to WordPress.

It also supports WordPress's leading event calendar plugin including  Timely’s All-in-One Event Calendar you are using.